# Play Framework & JSON: How to get an item of an array by value

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Grey",
  ...
  "addresses":
  [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Home",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Office",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    }
  ]
}
```

... how do I get let's say the item with `name` equal to `Home`?

```
    {
      "name": "Home",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links suggested by user1502304 does not provide any info on this topic. Furthermore, according to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/KoxPWtX2E-I/rpP2-H3hwtkJ) the current JSON library has some limitations... and as mentioned [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/943) the good alternative is `JsZipper`. That said, here below is how to get an item by value:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> import play.api.libs.json.extensions._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

scala> val user = Json.parse("""
     | {
     |   "firstName": "Joe",
     |   "lastName": "Grey",
     |   "isDefault": false,
     |   "addresses":
     |   [
     |     {
     |       "name": "Default",
     |       "street": "one",
     |       "isDefault": true
     |     },
     |     {
     |       "name": "Home",
     |       "street": "two",
     |       "isDefault": false
     |     },
     |     {
     |       "name": "Office",
     |       "street": "three",
     |       "isDefault": false
     |     }
     |   ]
     | }""")
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Grey","isDefault":false,"addresses":[{"name":"Default","street":"one","isDefault":true},{"name":"Home","street":"two","isDefault":false},{"name":"Office","street":"three","isDefault":false}]}

scala> JsZipper(json).findByValue(_ \ "name" == JsString("Default")).value
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"name":"Default","street":"one","isDefault":true}
```

I hope it helps.